# "В редкую стёжку" - откуда пошло такое выражение?

Tags: значение-слов

> Я ей в **редкую стёжку** буду пользоваться, в основном раз в месяц, но можно и больше.

Это не из литературы, просто некоторые люди так говорят. Вот стало интересно, откуда пошло такое выражение, и что означает слово `стёжка`?

> По [словарю Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/233310):
>
> - Шов, а также прошитое швом место. *Крупная с.*
> - То же, что тропинка. *С. во ржи. Позарастали стёжки-дорожки (о том, что прошло, забыто)*.

Но здесь явно не в этих значениях это слово употребляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое разговорное выражение, диалектный фразеологизм. Стёжка - тоже областное слово, пример даётся в транскрипции, чтобы передать диалектное произношение.

СТЁЖКА (областное от стега), -и, ж.  Тропинка, дорожка.  Как мос прайд'ет'а, ваз'л'е  р'ик'и с'т'ошка... тут  н'и  заблуд'иш (2).  Па  с'т'ошк'и пъ майой пашол, а пъ свайой  н'а  ход'ит' [сосед].  Надат'  γърад'ит'!  Гд'е  он  пъ  картошкам  пашол, с'т'ошкай-тъ  н'и  шол (1).

<>  **На (или  в) редкую стёжку  — изредка.**  Йа  на  Старай кан'ец р'етка ход'у [к родне]... на р'еткъйу с'т'ошку пайду,  а  то  нъдаис'  можна(15).  Зато какой пар'ин', н'иγд'е н'и работъит', накой йаво  д'оржыт', выбл'удаит'  дъ  иш'ш'о канф'ет купл'аит'... На нас шум'ат': бъγач'и — и то на р'еткъйу с'т'ошку б'ир'ом (2).  Ну  хърашо, м'ан'а н'амношкъ  пъч'итайит', хот'  в  р'еткуйу с'т'ошку (х).  В γорат када пайед'иш... уш на р'еткайу с'т'ошку йед'иш(29).

**В дальную стёжку  — поодаль, на значительном расстоянии**.  В  дал'нуйу  с'т'ошку  луч'ч'и  жыт'... пашол  прат'в'едал — и  дамой.

А вообще *стежка*-общеслав. суф. производное от стьга «тропа, дорога», имеющего соответствия в др. индоевроп. яз. (ср. латышск. stiga «тропа, просека», нем. Steg «тропинка», греч. stichos«строка, стих» и др.). См. достигать.

*Стежка вывела прямо в болото.* Л. Толстой .

*Позаносило стёжки-дорожки...*

Comment: Вот, из литературы (но в кавычках!):  _Вступив в 42-м году в Союз писателей, я посещал только собрания, на которых обсуждались вопросы художественного перевода, да и то – **«в редкую стежку»**._  https://books.google.ee/books?id=zREaAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT742&lpg=PT742&dq=%D0%B2+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D1%83&source=bl&ots=wyyjc4ex8c&sig=Yo3gKVsLaNgn4lpefcjYCts8gSY&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdtfSzitvaAhUFDuwKHVA2AAAQ6AEwAnoECAAQNQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D1%83&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Обычный сленг: ***в редкую стёжку*** ― это значит ***редко.***

Взят из швейной терминологии:

**Стёжка редкая** (расстояние между строчками более 20 мм). Стегают так обычно одеяла, чтобы изделие оставалось мягким и пушистым.

Примеры:

**В редкую стежку** бывает добрый юмор нынче.

Всегда у них какие-то дела, и обслужить клиента получается **в редкую стёжку**.

Для многих горожан, **в редкую стёжку** выбирающихся за город «на природу», лес, как правило, остаётся просто лесом.

Вообще говоря, звучит не всегда красиво, слишком в разных ситуациях применяется эта форма. Мало образности и тонкого юмора, которые иногда вызывают симпатию в сленговых выражениях.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Не сомнений, что исходным является слово ***стезя***, отсюда все стёжки-дорожки, и только потом шов и даже следы, похожие на такой шов.

**Стежка** (тропинка) бывает узкой, извилистой, а вот выражение "редкая стёжка" часто ли встречается? Что это,  дорога, по которой редко ходят? И уж совсем неясен винительный падеж - ***в редкую стежку***, это уж скорее всего не о дорожке-тропинке. Это только тетради бывают в клетку и в линейку ― обычное значение В.п. для наречного выражения.

Так что с трудом верится, что областная ***стежка*** вдруг преобразилась в не очень ясную падежную форму  "в редкую стежку"и стала популярной в современной молодежной речи.

Comment: Да я и не говорю, что это от значения "тропка". Я попыталась сказать, что здесь как раз объединились те два значения, отвергнутые автором вопроса, которые есть у Ожегова. Просто в литературном языке они разделились, а в Рязани до сих пор существуют вместе. В культуре донских казаков стегать одеяла - часть национальной культуры, их жизнь, их путь. Потому у них и одеяло в редкую стёжку = редко стёганное, и дела в редкую стёжку, так же как и в  дальную = дорожки швов далеко друг от друга,  и жить лучше вдали от родни (чем дальше, тем роднее). Это не молодёжный сленг, а диалект.

Answer (score 0):

Длинная нитка - ленивая портниха. Крупный стежок - редкий стежок. Игла появляется из материала и снова уходит в материал. И вместе с ней нить делает стежок - появляется на поверхности. Но на обратной стороне тоже появляется стежок - невидимый сверху. Вот и получается - если стежок короткий - он частый. А если стежок крупный - он редкий. Нитка-то на обратной стороне тянется на большую длину! :)
Поэтому и значение выражения - редко, время от времени.